# How to select contact number from contact list using android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

[Look at my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqMHz.png)

How do I get the selected contact's number & name from contact list.

Comment: What you have tried ?>

Comment: Look at my screenshot

Comment: And where is your code? a screenshot is not enough.

Comment: Below is my source code

Answer (score 10):

onClick code

```
 Intent pickContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
 pickContact.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE)
 startActivityForResult(pickContact, 1);
```

onActivityResult code

```
 Uri contactData = data.getData();
 Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
 if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                   int phoneIndex = getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                   String num = c.getString(phoneIndex);
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Number=" + num, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
```

Comment: Thank you, your code works great. I have just 2 extra hints.  

If the user does not select a contact, app will crash. You can solve it by checking in `onActivityResult` that `resultCode == -1` (which the system returns when something is picked).  

Instead of raw number, you might want to use `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER`, which is formatted by some international standard regardless of what the user entered into the contact list.

Answer (score 4):

To get contact name, number as well as email also of a selected contact from your contact list, you just need to simply add this code.

```
private Button btn;
private String TAG = "Contacts";
private static final int RESULT_PICK_CONTACT = 1;


btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
selectSingleContact();
    }
});

private void selectSingleContact() {   
Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, RESULT_PICK_CONTACT);
}    

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// check whether the result is ok
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    // Check for the request code, we might be usign multiple startActivityForResult
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RESULT_PICK_CONTACT:
            contactPicked(data);
            break;
    }
} else {
    Log.e("ContactFragment", "Failed to pick contact");
       }
}

private void contactPicked(Intent data) {

Uri uri = data.getData();
Log.i(TAG, "contactPicked() uri " + uri.toString());
Cursor cursor;
ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();

try {
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (null != cur && cur.getCount() > 0) {
        cur.moveToFirst();
        for (String column : cur.getColumnNames()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "contactPicked() Contacts column " + column + " : " + cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(column)));
        }
    }

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
      //Query the content uri
        cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

        if (null != cursor && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            for (String column : cursor.getColumnNames()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "contactPicked() uri column " + column + " : " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(column)));
            }
        }

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        Log.i(TAG, "contactPicked() uri id " + id);
        String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
        Log.i(TAG, "contactPicked() uri contact id " + contact_id);
        // column index of the contact name
        name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        // column index of the phone number
        phoneNo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        //get Email id of selected contact....
        Log.e("ContactsFragment", "::>> " + id + name + phoneNo);

        Cursor cur1 = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{contact_id}, null);

        if (null != cur1 && cur1.getCount() > 0) {
            cur1.moveToFirst();
            for (String column : cur1.getColumnNames()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "contactPicked() Email column " + column + " : " + cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(column)));
                email = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
            }

           //HERE YOU GET name, phoneno & email of selected contact from contactlist.....
            Log.e("setcontactDetails","::>>" + name+"\nPhoneno:" + phoneNo+"\nEmail: " + email);
        } else {
            Log.e("setcontactDetails","::>>" + name+"\nPhoneno:" + phoneNo+"\nEmail: " + email);
        }
    }
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also add permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml
It works for me, hope it will works for you also.

Comment: This is massively inefficient. moveToFirst returns a boolean, which is false if null. There is no need to keep null checking the cursor and issuing extraneous queries.

Answer (score -2):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_usercontact);

    class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private final int REQUEST_CODE=99;
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.content_usercontact);
            EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextcontacts1);
            EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextcontacts2);
            EditText editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextcontacts3);
            editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            });

            editText1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            });

            editText2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            });

        }


        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
            switch (reqCode) {
                case (REQUEST_CODE):
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Uri contactData = data.getData();
                        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                            String contactId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                            String hasNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                            String num = "";
                            if (Integer.valueOf(hasNumber) == 1) {
                                Cursor numbers = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                                while (numbers.moveToNext()) {
                                    num = numbers.getString(numbers.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Number=" + num, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.